# Check if n*m area can be filled with a*b sized tiles and find the remainder

Tags: geometry, area

How can I mathematically check if $n\times m$ area can be filled with pieces with $a \times b$ area and find the remainder?

For example, can $6\times 6$ area be filled with $1 \times4$ tiles? My made up notation and answer is as follows:

```
  6*6 = 6*(1*4) + 6*2
  6*2 = 2*(4*1) + 2*2
  6*6 mod 1*4 = 2*2 hence it can't be filled with 1*4 tiles.
```

This one is just written to fit the answer I've found mechanically and not valid notation. Is there a valid rigorous way to do this for any $n\times m$ sized area and $1 \times4$ sized tiles?

**How to find the area of the reminder?**

Comment: The general solution is given by Klarner's Theorem, which I detail in [this Community Wiki answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1459556/3111).  See also the other answer there by fellow Knoxvillian @GrumpyParsnip, which provides a proof.

Comment: I didn't find that with search. I didn't search with keyword `grid` because I thought `n x m` is not necessarily a grid

Comment: Often the Google search is better at finding previous answers than the SE search feature, but in this case I had success with search terms "tiling rectangles" before I remembered my own post!

Comment: Seems like people are missing other point of the question. Updated my question.

Comment: Would that be because you've only introduced the idea of *remainder* size in this last edit?  Readers can check the edit history to see the original version for themselves.  The other nuance you have introduced is changing $a$ by $b$ tiles to tiles with $a \times b$ area, which if liberally interpreted permits varying tile shapes so long as they each have area $ab$.  Readers trying to answer your Question are apt to be frustrated if it is a moving target.

Comment: I don't understand your statement "6*6 mod 1*4 = 2*2", since $6\cdot6 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.

Comment: That is just a made up non valid notation. Because I don't know the valid one. Also I need to know the answer to the remainder area. Stop marking this as a duplicate. That question is only about checking.